# Want to move from 000webhost to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I use 000webost - https://members.000webhost.com/ - its a free server for life and it allows PHP. It just limited to like 100mb bandwidth. Which is more then enough for my small website. They give me a free domain too, of course its not great its like `what_i_want.blah.blah.net` where the `blah` is randomly selected by them on setup.

I wanted to do the same on AWS, but AWS is taking my credit card information and the free tier expires after 12 months, at which point I'm afraid they'll start billing my card without me even knowing. I can't even figure out how to set up this stuff on AWS its so complicated. They're free list is here - https://aws.amazon.com/free/ - and it's gosh darn ENDLESS, with nothing saying `hosting with free subdomain`.

Is it possible to use AWS like 00webhost? Free for life just low bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one year AWS will give you some free services.  It is quite possible that you will be charged some small amount (like $.40/month) if you use VPNs (which I would recommend).  Their small free tier server will cost you about $70/mon once it isn't free.  You could possibly keep shifting sites around, but there is a pretty decent learning curve on AWS to keep from ending up owing them a fortune.  Don't start RDBS, for instance, for a want-it-to-be-free website.

If it's just the name bugging you, buy a domain name and redirect it to the site.  If they let you run PHP scripts, they may let you run an Apache domain rewrite rule in an .htaccess file.

Edit: @Notidart, And please be very careful when working on AWS.  It is very EASY to build something that isn't free there.  Data sent into AWS is not charged for transfer.  Data sent out either to the internet or into another AWS region is charged for the transfer.  The free tier will give you some data for free.  Setting up email sending on their servers is time-consuming, but can be done.  They block it by default to prevent spammers from using multiple free servers to send email.  I have been working with one small group that created a software that used a mysql database that they put on RDBS and ran on one web server.  Everything was fine until the year was up and suddenly in one month they had a $700 bill for what was essentially a website that was not servicing Anyone.  (no connections in or out --it was just server time/RDBS time charged).  I actually make a very good living managing cloud services so that businesses don't end up with cost overruns.  I would recommend trying AWS, but you need to be cautious and be very aware of what is in the free tier and what is not.  VPNs, load balancers, are not in the free tier.  It's hard to create a site that is Continuous Deployment/Integration within the free tier constraints.

If you aren't into deep systems administration skills, keep the free webhost and learn how to set up a domain name rewrite rule.  It's going to be a lot cheaper for you.

Comment: Thanks very much ScotT for your fast reply. I need to run PHP because I need to do `curl` for some libraries I'm using. 40 cents a month would be super perfect, would that come with a free subdomain, I don't really care about name? Do you know of a guide for this?

Comment: I tried following this tutorial a couple times but failed miserably each time - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/web-app-hosting-intro.html - and after hours I still couldn't find phpmyadmin-similar interface, or mysql database option.

Comment: @Notidart, Think of AWS as bare metal servers.  You're going to have to build all of your tools and will have to know a lot of basic admin stuff.  You won't have phpmyadmin or mysql unless you build it on the server.

Comment: I'm giving you the Cliff Notes on AWS services.  If you are at the level where you need phpmyadmin to run your website, I would NOT suggest jumping to AWS.  It could get really deep, really quick.  And Bezos is not kind to Newbies who make innocent mistakes.  I'd suggest learning by building something and then deleting it at the end of your learning session each day.  It takes discipline, but $1.48/hr adds up over a 1 month period.

Comment: Thank you very much for such awesome notes and warning, I sincerely appreciate it. I'll take your advice and stay on 000webhost and just learn AWS for awhile with the throws aways you recommend. Thank you!